# How do I get the character pressed in a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is really weird.

I have a textarea. 
I listen to the keyup and keypress events.

When I press "(", keypress is fired with e.keyCode == e.which == 40

When I press the arrow down key, keyup is fired with e.keyCode == e.which == 40

Why is this so strange?

Comment: By `(` you mean holding shift and pressing 9, correct?

Comment: Which browser are you using?  With keypress in chrome with jquery, I am unable to capture arrow keys.  `(` does give me 40, which is the ascii code for that character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`keydown` and `keyup` events provide a code indicating which **key** is pressed, while `keypress` indicates which **character** was entered.

Char code for "(" is 40 (`keypress` event) and key code for down arrow is also 40 (`keyup`).

Try:

```
String.fromCharCode(40); // "("
```

Answer (score 3):

Traditionally, the arrow keys overlapped ASCII codes, but were represented to the programmer as a two-byte sequence so you were aware that a special key has been pressed.  With the advent of Unicode this is no longer a clean solution.

Browsers have implemented different ways of representing special key input to the Javascript runtime. The details are [explained here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptjunkie/ff928319).

I usually use the 'keydown' event when detecting arrow keys, as this event has the correct keycode attached and will fire with a different keycode(the one for 9) when the user is typing a left parenthesis.  This may not work in cases where you want to allow the user to repeat the keyed event by holding down the arrow key.